# Javascript is not called on radiobutton list index change

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have written code for javascript but it is not called any how. I tried to call both form html side and also by assigning attribute from page load event but it is not at all called.

This is the code for my javascript.

```
function rdbantiplatelet_onClick(thiscontrol, trName) {
    alert('hi');
    var RB1 = thiscontrol;
    var radio = RB1.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var trDose = document.getElementById(trName.toString());
//  var RB1 = document.getElementById("<%=this.rdbantiplatelet.ClientID%>");
//  var radio = RB1.getElementsByTagName("input");
//  var tblAntiplatelet = document.getElementById("<%=tblAntiplatelet.ClientID %>");

    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
        if (radio[i].checked){
            trDose.style.display = "";
            return true;
        }
        else{
            trDose.style.display = "none";
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

This is the code to call javascript written in page_load event..

```
rdbantiplatelet.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return rdbantiplatelet_onClick(this,'" +  trDose.ClientID.ToString() + "');");
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error? Have you checked the console?

Comment: I understand that nothing is happening, but do you get an error? Have you viewed the source on the page to ensure that the function call exists in the markup?

Comment: @James Hill ..Yes the function call exists if I view page source. And not getting any error. Console is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an `alert()` first to make sure your `onclick` is firing, then try your `rdbantiplatelet_onClick()` function:

```
rdbantiplatelet.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "alert('I am working');");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all for your reference here is a list of standard html events

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

try adding something like this to the html radiobutton element

onchange="alert('on change fired');"

and

onclick="alert(' on click fired');

so you can make sure you are picking up the right event.

Once you have the right event then replace the alert call to your method

which would be something like this

onchange="rdbantiplatelet_onClick(this, this.parent.id)"

...you might have to change the 'this.parent.id'

Make sure you are running through a good web browser for development FireFox with the firebug plug-in is great for this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You are add click event to html table that holds radiobuttons. Use script below:

```
foreach (ListItem item in rdbantiplatelet.Items)
{
    item.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return foobar(this);");
}
```